# LinkedHashMap iterating over the keys

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

I can't confirm this in the documentation but if i have a LinkedHashMap and i call keySet() on it and iterate over this set is it guaranteed to iterate in insertion order?

Answer (score 3):

It's specified in the [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) documentation:

> The `Map` interface provides three collection views, which allow a map's contents to be viewed as a set of keys, collection of values, or set of key-value mappings. The order of a map is defined as the order in which the iterators on the map's collection views return their elements. Some map implementations, like the `TreeMap` class, make specific guarantees as to their order; others, like the HashMap class, do not.

That means for `LinkedHashMap`, all the 3 methods - `values()`, `keySet()` and `entrySet()`, each of them providing 3 different collection views, are guaranteed to iterate in the insertion order.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.
See the docs(that you can not see) here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Map interface, with
>   predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashMap
>   in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its
>   entries. This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is
>   normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map
>   (insertion-order). Note that insertion order is not affected if a key
>   is re-inserted into the map. (A key k is reinserted into a map m if
>   m.put(k, v) is invoked when m.containsKey(k) would return true
>   immediately prior to the invocation.)